# Why do we calculate the median the way that we do?

Tags: statistics

If we have 4 Apples:

A A A A

Then in any stats class, the medium is 2.5.

I am very sure that this is wrong, and that the medium is actually 2, even though experts in the field would say otherwise. Yeah, I know that's arrogant, but I cannot think of why you have 2.5 as being the medium, which is here:

```
| A | A | A | A |
--+---+---+---+
 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5
          ^
          |
       2.5 is
         Here
```

When 2 is here:

```
| A | A | A | A |
+---+---+---+---+
0   1   2   3   4
        ^
        |
      Here
```

(I mean just look at it!)

My stats teacher can't even think of why 2.5 is the median, it's like somewhere someone made a mistake and has been accepted as the norm. Can someone please, please explain otherwise. I cannot see it, I can't, why 2.5? why not 2, it's just 1/2 of 4.

If you were counting 5, then 1/2 of 5 is 2.5, not 3, if you were to say 3, you only count the three after 3 *whole* numbers. Yes, it's true that there are 2 numbers left and right of three, but 2.5 is slap bang in the middle, half of 4 is dead on centre, that being 2, and this *after* 2.5 in the case of 5, and *after* 2 in the case of 4, why don't we go with this convention? You know, like we do in geometry, algebra, calculus, and combinatorics, why do things change in stats?

I mean take the area of a triangle with base 4, 1/2 base times height. It's not 2.5 times the height, it's 2.

I can do just fine in stats in calculating the medium, but I **Cannot** accept that this is right without reason, and fail to see why I would use this convention in my potential career in mathematics.

Comment: First, you don't mean "medium." You should start by getting the word right. The word you are looking for is "median." Second, the reason you don't understand this is that you don't know what the definition of the median is. Things don't "change in stats." You are just confused.

Comment: *"If you were counting 5 ... it's true that there are 2 numbers left and right of three"* is the key point to understanding.

Comment: You corrected your confusion? Look up the formal definition of the word "median" and your problem will be solved. (It is by definition the 50th percentile of the data. In the case of discrete data sets such as $\left\{1,2,3,4\right\}$, there are actually many medians, but by convention, to get a unique number, we set it to be the average of the middle two.) It is not a giant conspiracy or a mistake that has been accepted as the norm. The sooner you realize how ridiculous that sounds, the sooner you'll be able to diagnose your own confusion.

Comment: Yes, but, why is that the convention, why is that better than just dividing by 2, I know the how, not the why, and it seems that everyone I ask fails in providing the latter. Leading me to my premise that this may not be wrong per se, but at least not the better way. By the way, if  the median by definition, is the 50th percentile of the given data, well, 1/2 is the fractional notation for 50%, it's not like it's a personal choice, 50% must be, and only be, 1/2.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to say. There is no medium in stats. A medium might be a size of your soft drink at a fast food place or possibly someone who can communicate with the spirit world, but I can't think of any standard meaning it would have in statistics.

**Median** on the other hand does have a definition but seems to have little to do with what you are talking about. Certainly you can't take the median of four apples, and it won't help if you try oranges.

A **median** in statistics is defined for a list of values taken to be real. In that case it is defined to be the middle value when you sort the list in ascending order and the number of elements is odd or the average of the two "middle" values if the list has an even number of elements. This automatically tells you that to be able to even try to talk about a median of some (finite) list you need a total order on the elements and if there is an even number of them you need to have a notion of average on the elements.

None of these conditions are satisfied by your apples and as such they don't lend themselves to a reasonable extension of the idea of a median.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be quite confused about the use of the **median**. Typically, you find the median of a **set of numbers**, not a single number. Your initial example has you finding the median of four apples, which doesn't really make sense. Imagine, instead, you have a set of buckets containing apples. Suppose you have four buckets, containing 1, 2, 3, and 4 apples. The median number of apples in the buckets is 2.5. Here, there are two "middle numbers" (2 and 3), so the convention is to take the average of them. Corresponding to your second example, imagine now you have five buckets of apples, containing 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 apples. Now the median number of apples in the buckets is 2 (simply the middle number). As another example, suppose you have three buckets, containing 1, 101, and 102 apples. Now the median is 101. Looking at a number line and trying to guess where the middle of the set looks like it should be isn't the way to go about this - just order the numbers in your **set** and pick the middle one.

Comment: Hey... That actually works! Your reinterpretation of my apple analogy actually makes a lot of sense,  your analogy makes things click a little, especially in distinguishing between the choice one can have between 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4, apples, and 0 OR 1 OR 2 etc. –

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you confuse two problems. You have $4$ apples, but can you choose to have $0$ apple or not?

In this case, the value you can choose from are $\left\{0,1,2,3,4\right\}$.

In the other case, you can choose from $\left\{1,2,3,4\right\}$...

Comment: Mmm, true, I can sort of see your reasoning, but when counting one we go from 0 to 1 right? So in the data set {1,2,3,4}, wouldn't the 0 be presumed as we had to 'jump up' from 0 to get to 1.

Comment: We don't "jump" from one value to an other. We choose a number from either $0...4$ or $1...4$ and then we want to know the average value, the median etc... There is no progression. When you have to choose from $1...4$, $0$ has not meaning whatsoever in this context. Think of choosing from $456$ to $896$...

Comment: Yes, your right, in choosing between 4 items and keeping track of the distance of four miles are 2 very different concepts, such as that 'jump' from distance 0 through to 1 mile. In a choice of 4 though I must admit that there is no such progression. Though still, 2 is half of 4 choices... Anyway, I'll bare this difference in mind as I try to understand current conventions, so thank you very much! :)